# How to align text to the right of automatic slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I am having trouble aligning text with an automatic slideshow I created. I want the text to appear to the right of the slideshow, which it is, but lower.

I'm new to HTML/CSS so please excuse my ineptitude.

When trying to resolve this issue, I can only find information on aligning text next to single images. I tried using `float: left;` but I'm not getting the results I'm looking for.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}
.mySlides {display: none;}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 110px;
}

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h2 style="font-size: 15px; margin-left: 900px; display: inline;">Here     but lower. How??</h2>

<div class="slideshow-container">

 <div class="mySlides fade">
 <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg" style="width: 750px" height="350px">
  <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
  <img src="http://blog.eternalvigilance.me/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/dont-tread-on-me.png" style="width: 750px" height="350px">
  <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade">
  <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
<img src="https://natgeo.imgix.net/factsheets/thumbnails/Nature-Ocean-Wave.jpg?auto=compress,format&w=1024&h=560&fit=crop" style="width: 750px" height="350px">
  <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
</div>

</div>
<br>

<div style="margin-left: 450px">
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
  <span class="dot"></span> 
</div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 4000); // Change image every 4 seconds
}
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand what you want with header text. Your output should be look like this [image]

You need to add div wrappers in your HTML ode as well as its CSS declaration.
Here is your Code.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>

* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;}
.mySlides {display: none;}
img {vertical-align: middle;}

.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}
.container .box { 
                margin:50px; 
                display:table; 
            } 
            .container .box .box-row { 
                display:table-row; 
                width : 120%;
            } 
            .container .box .box-cell.box1 { 

                text-align:justify; 
             } 
            .container .box .box-cell { 
                display:table-cell; 
            }
            .container .box .box-cell.box2 { 
                text-align:justify;
                padding-left: 10px;
            } 
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="box-row">

                <div class="slideshow-container box-cell box1">

                    <div class="mySlides fade">
                        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
                        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg"
                            style="width: 750px" height="350px">
                        <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mySlides fade">
                        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
                        <img src="http://blog.eternalvigilance.me/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/dont-tread-on-me.png"
                            style="width: 750px" height="350px">
                        <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mySlides fade">
                        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
                        <img src="https://natgeo.imgix.net/factsheets/thumbnails/Nature-Ocean-Wave.jpg?auto=compress,format&w=1024&h=560&fit=crop"
                            style="width: 750px" height="350px">
                        <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="box-cell box2">
                    <h2 style="font-size: 15px;">Here but lower. How??</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <div style="margin-left: 450px">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
    </div>

<script>
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  setTimeout(showSlides, 4000); // Change image every 4 seconds
}
</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If still your issue is not resolved Please let me know in comments.

Comment: Changing text-align from center to right only alters the caption, which is not what I'm trying to do. I am trying to move the header slightly lower without moving the slideshow.

Comment: Here     but lower. How?? - This header you want to slightly lower than the actual one but it above the slide show ?